# 'SKNode!' is not a subtype of 'SKNode'

Tags: swift

I can't figure out why I am getting this error on the last line: 'SKNode!' is not a subtype of 'SKNode'

```
func move_background(){
    let enumerationBlock: (SKNode, CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void = { bg, stop in
        var bg_velocity = CGPointMake(0,CGFloat(-self.bg_velocity))
        var distance_to_move = self.point_multiply_scalar(bg_velocity, b: self.dt!)
        bg.position = self.point_add(bg.position, b: distance_to_move)

        if bg.position.y <= -bg.frame.height {
            bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x, bg.position.y + bg.frame.height * 2)
        }
    }

    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("bg", usingBlock: enumerationBlock)

}
```

Can any of you help me out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the SKNode class, the block argument to this message is of the type `(void (^)(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop))`

When Swift imports an Objective-C class, all of its message arguments and return values are imported as optionals -- arguments you pass to functions are always `NSString?` or `NDSData?`, not just `NSString` or `NSData`.  They do this because all pointers in Obj-C can be nil, but a `var` in Swift *can't* be nil unless it has a question mark at the end, thus making it an "optional" type.

So when you define your `enmuerationBlock`, it should be of the type

```
(SKNode?, CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void
```

---

#### EDIT answering flainez's question below:

When you have a mutable pointer, you dereference it by obtaining an `UnsafePointer` thus

```
var val :CMutablePointer<Bool> = /* get this from somewhere */

val.withUnsafePointer() { (p :UnsafePointer<Bool>) in
    p.memory = true /* or whatever */
}
```

`.withUnsafePointer` yields an `UnsafePointer<T>` to the block, and `UnsafePointer<T>` has a memory property that is assignable.

**Annoying:** You can't test this in the Playground's REPL, it always fails, but it works when you compile it to a proper target.

Comment: Also this implies that your whole block should be in a `let-as` block that makes sure SKNode isn't null.

Comment: I mean `if-let`,  sorry new to me too.

Comment: Any idea on how you can set the BOOL *stop to true? If I try to do: `let enumerationBlock: (SKNode, CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void = { bg, stop in stop = true }` I get an error saying that I can't write on a let variable.

Comment: It's a good question, there are several questions here that are basically "how do I dereference a pointer once I have one?"  I dunno, and when it comes to this the Playground and regular build targets seem to behave differently.  Have you looked in the header? Maybe there's some setter on the C*Pointer generics I haven't seen yet.